# "Not Found" error when linking a section of a page within the same page

Tags: html

I am trying to link a word on my page that jumps to a different part farther down on the same page, however, when I add the class to the div and the href to the linking word, it opens a new page that says "Not Found"

What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="paragraph">If you are installing panels on both walls and 
ceiling, it is recommended to do the ceiling first. The ceiling can also be 
installed at a later date.
<ul><li>See warnings on Radiant Tube Heater installation - <em>Section 
5.3</em></li>
<li>See Special Instructions&nbsp;for installation in cold temperatures - 
<em>Section 5.1</em></li>
<li>See Recommended Fasteners - <em><u><a 
href="recommended_fasteners">Section 4.1</a></em></u></li></ul></div>

<div class="recommended_fasteners"
style="text-align:right;">
<strong>SECTION 4.1</strong></div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a hash there. To make sure you don't navigate from the page, you need to add a hash to the URL. Use this:

```html
<div class="paragraph">If you are installing panels on both walls and 
ceiling, it is recommended to do the ceiling first. The ceiling can also be 
installed at a later date.
<ul><li>See warnings on Radiant Tube Heater installation - <em>Section 
5.3</em></li>
<li>See Special Instructions&nbsp;for installation in cold temperatures - 
<em>Section 5.1</em></li>
<li>See Recommended Fasteners - <em><u><a 
href="#recommended_fasteners">Section 4.1</a></em></u></li></ul></div><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div id="recommended_fasteners"
style="text-align:right;">
<strong>SECTION 4.1</strong></div>
```

Comment: That works, thank you so much!! The only thing I would like now is for when the page jumps to the section, for the title "Section 4.1" to appear above the text instead of it cutting off the "Section 4.1" title. Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: @Kaylee I didn't get it. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Your technique for jumping to the different section of the page worked. But when it jumps to that point, the title "Section 4.1" is cut off by the top of the window, and only the text underneath the title "Section 4.1" is shown, followed by the rest of the page. How would I make it so the title "Section 4.1" is not cut off by the top of the window when it jumps down to that section of the page?

Comment: @Kaylee that should not really happen. Check if you're doing something wrong with CSS styling. For eg, check some same sort of "jump" links here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/introduction.html

Comment: Okay, I think it's something to do with how my nav bar is styled... Last question, when jumping to this section of the page from a different page, how would I link to it? Would I add the url of the page in the 'href' on the different page and then the 'div id' after?

Comment: @Kayle for jumping from a.html to b.html and this section, use href="b.html#recommended_fasteners"